# cosine similarity of large data in python

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

dataset['Review_Text'] contains 194439 reviews.
coding given below to calculate the cosine similarity between these reviews.

```
v= TfidfVectorizer()
X = v.fit_transform(dataset['Review_Text'].values.astype('U'))
S = cosine_similarity(X)
```

error:
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Comment: Well, yes. If you want to calculate the cossim between every review and every other review, you need a matrix of shape roughly 200K x 200K. Do you realise how big that is going to get?

Comment: Also, using pandas and sklearn isn't the same as using sklearn-pandas, that's a separate module altogether.

Comment: when i am applying same coding on 5000 reviews its gives expected and proper results.